# Better location filtering or content monitoring for job emails

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I am specifically looking for jobs in *Wellington* or *Christchurch* in New Zealand and I'm happy with emails I receive notifying for job opening in these areas and don't have any objection at all.

Problem appears when the jobs listed in email are all over place except New Zealand such as USA and Singapore (really?)!

I received another email a few weeks ago which only included jobs from The Netherlands and Germany and text of the ad was all written in Dutch and German, which obviously I can't read (I didn't specify either language in my languages list).

It becomes worse when the title of the ad says *Visa sponsor* and *Paid relocation* but in the description of the job says you should be resident of the country or have work permit to apply.

I wish there was more strict filtering for jobs specially on location and language. I'm not sure if it would be possible to have more monitoring on content of the ads or may be a contact or comment on job that we can let the advertiser know their advertise content does not make sense!

Comment: Were the hits for the Netherlands for jobs in Zeeland?

Comment: Or [*"Zealand"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zealand)?

Answer (score 6):

I checked your alert history and you had 5 alerts configured, 4 of which were for a location-based search and 1 was a text-based search for `new zealand`.

The last email you received only contained jobs for that last alert (`new zealand`).

If I [search /jobs for `new zealand`](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=new+zealand) it expands the query out to:

`(new or zealand)^1 or (new and zealand)^10 or ("new zealand")^100`

The `^{n}` specifiers indicate the relative weight given to each part of the query. Given the first part of the query effectively finds everything with the word 'new' in it you're going to get a lot of hits, including those that bear absolutely no relationship to the literal phrase `new zealand`.

So, in essence this is working exactly as it is supposed to - you configured an alert for `new zealand` and you got back everything that matched that query.

We already have strict filtering for locations - type a query into the location box. Admittedly we can probably do better with detecting locations typed into the text part of the search, but that's pretty complex to get right which is why, for now, we've avoided doing it!